# Convert :It() function jquery to angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change this code to angular , I write part of code but I don't know what should I use replace of :It() . jquery code is in this url : [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/3999/)

and my angular code is this :

```
    x = 3;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 3; //show article in page when page load . this code is replace of : " $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show(); "
    sizeLi = $scope.articles.length; //sizeLi return count of my articles . Replace of : " $("#myList li").size(); "
    $('#loadMore').click(function() {
          x = (x + 5 <= sizeLi) ? x + 5 : sizeLi;
          **$scope.articles.push($scope.articles[x]); // Replace of : " $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show(); "**
          return false;
    });
```

Comment: Can use `limitTo` filter on your ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

According to your `jsfiddle` you can achieve this in angular by using `limitTo` and add two function to set limitTo range

in controller:

```
  $scope.limit = 1;
  $scope.articles = [
    'one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten'
    ];

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
      var sizeLi = $scope.articles.length;
      var x = $scope.limit;
      x = (x + 5 <= sizeLi) ? x + 5 : sizeLi;
      $scope.limit =x;
    };

    $scope.showLess = function() {
      var sizeLi = $scope.articles.length;
      var x = $scope.limit;
      x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
      $scope.limit =x;
    };
```

and HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li ng-repeat="articale in articles | limitTo : limit : 0">{{articale}}</li>
</ul>
<div style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="loadMore()" >Load more</div>
<div style="cursor:pointer"  ng-click="showLess()">Show less</div>
```

Updated **HTML** to show or hide load more and less button

```
<div style="cursor:pointer;color:green" ng-click="loadMore()" ng-show="limit<articles.length">Load more</div>
<div style="cursor:pointer;color:red"  ng-click="showLess()" ng-show="limit>0">Show less</div>
```

For more see [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/wtva8l3Hyznt5Ajodejb?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Shaishab Roy , I used from your code . So thanks , It works very well , but it has a problem : when page load and first I click on "showLess" , it works like "loadMore" . What should I do for it ?

Comment: use  `x=(x-5<0) ? 0 : x-5;` in `showLess` function instead of `x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;` @mahdikhodadadian

Comment: I forgot a part that say to you . It is : when the articles show completely (that there isn't any article other to show) , Other don't show button (div) loadMore . َActually hidden it . So thanks

Comment: I forgot a part that say to you . It is : when the articles show completely (that there isn't any article other to show) , Other don't show button (div) loadMore . َActually hidden it . So thanks